# how to store byte string in byte[] using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, entity-framework

I have

> 0x4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF0000B80000000000000040...

generated from sql server.

How can I insert byte `string` into `byte[]` column in database using EntityFramework?

Comment: Are you *sure* you have it as a string? I would expect SQL Server to return that as a byte[], but most tools will *represent* it as a string in the form `0x{hex}`. Is there any reason you can't have SQL Server just return the `varbinary` ?

Comment: we are writing custom tool for default data management.

Comment: @Ravinda that doesn't tell me why you are representing binary data as text... there should be no need to do that. A `varbinary(max)` to store the binary should be fine.

Comment: we are storing byte string in excel to import using entity framework.

Comment: Yet you mention sql server repeatedly and Excel never... you can see why this would be confusing, I hope

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment above, I strongly suspect that the best thing to do here is to **return the data as a byte[] from the server**; this should be fine and easy to do. However, if you *have* to use a `string`, then you'll need to parse it out - take off the `0x` prefix, divide the length by 2 to get the number of bytes, then loop and parse each 2-character substring using `Convert.ToByte(s, 16)` in turn. Something like (completely untested):

```
int len = (value.Length / 2)-1;
var arr = new byte[len];
for(int i = 0; i < len;i++) {
    var s = value.Substring((i + 1) * 2, 2);
    arr[i] = Convert.ToByte(s, 16);
}
```